# Object fetched in constructor but not shown in VF page

Tags: visualforce, custom-object

I am new to SalesForce and developing on the platform, and I am running into issues displaying data from a custom object I created to a custom VisualForce page. Here is my code for the apex class:

```
public class WellCompany {
 public WellCompany__c wellcompany {get;set;}
 public WellCompany()
 {
 String Name = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
 List<WellCompany__c>wellcompany = [Select Name From WellCompany__c  where Id='Name'];
 }
 public PageReference save() {
 update wellcompany;
 return new PageReference('/' + wellcompany.Name);
}
}
```

And here is the code for the custom VisualForce page:

```
<apex:page Controller="WellCompany" >
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Company Detail">
            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
            < apex:pageBlockSection title="Company Information" columns="2">
                <apex:outputText value="{!wellcompany.Name}" /> 
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>    
    <apex:form>
<apex:page>
```

Comment: What is your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a misconception between the standard fields of Name and ID

ID is an 18 character value that is unique to every SFDC record in the universe
Name is either a user-input field (like Opportunity.Name) or an autonumber field.

Your controller should read (note use of :bind variable in select where clause). Note I removed the list as the target of the select as if you retrieve by ID you will get only one record.

```
public class WellCompany {
 public WellCompany__c wellcompany {get;set;}
 public WellCompany()
 {
 ID wcId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
 wellcompany = [Select Id,  Name From WellCompany__c  where Id=:wcId];  // fetch into vbl w getter
 }
 public PageReference save() {
 update wellcompany;
 PageReference resPg;
 return new PageReference('/' + wellcompany.id);
}
}
```

Comment: I fixed the code - error was in constructor which I shouldn't have blindly copied from your OP. You had two variables for wellcompany - one declared inside the constructor and not visible to the page and the separate variable with the getter. The constructor in your OP was fetching the record but storing it in a local vbl.